# Prove that $(T\cdot x)^T\cdot(T\cdot y) = x^T\cdot y$ using another proven identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

First part was to prove the following identity:

$(1)\space \space \space x^T\cdot y=0.25\cdot(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2), \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

This I have done. Now the next part is to use equation (1) in order to prove (2):

$(2)\space \space \space (T\cdot x)^T\cdot(T\cdot y) = x^T\cdot y, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^3$

Unfortunately I haven't managed to prove it yet.. I'm hoping for any tips or guidelines if possible.

-Elia

Comment: What is $T$? What do you know about it?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's an orthonormal transformation matrix of dimension (3x3).

Comment: The second equation is not true for a general $3 \times 3$ matrix. You need some assumption on $T$ (for example, that $T$ is orthogonal).

Comment: I edited my comment just about when you were replying :)

Comment: And what is your definition of an orthonormal transformation matrix?

Comment: $T^T\cdot T=T^{-1}\cdot T=\mathbf{I}$ and it preserves the length of a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your definition of an orthogonal transformation is that $T^T \cdot T = I$ then you don't need the first identity to prove the second identity. You can use the properties of transpose and matrix multiplication and deduce that

$$ (T \cdot x)^T \cdot (T \cdot y) = (x^T \cdot T^T) \cdot (T \cdot y) = x^T \cdot (T^T \cdot T) \cdot y = x^T \cdot I \cdot y = x^T \cdot y. $$

If, however, your definition of an orthogonal transformation is that $||T(x)|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then using the first identity and the linearity of $T$ you can see that

$$ (T \cdot x)^T \cdot (T \cdot y) = \frac{1}{4} \left( ||Tx + Ty||^2 - ||Tx - Ty||^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( ||T(x+y)||^2 - ||T(x-y)||^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( ||x+y||^2 - ||x-y||^2 \right) = x^T \cdot y. $$

Comment: The second part of your answer where $||T(x)||=||x||$ was exactly the part I was missing. Thank you very much.